# how to extarct from a list based on sign changing?

Tags: python

I have a file like below

```
num   col2  col3 
 0     2.4  -0.3
 1     2.2  -0.2
 2     1.4  -0.1
 3    -2.3   1.0
 4    -1.5   0.3
 5    -2.0   0.1
 6    -2.2   0.07
 7     2.0  -0.01
```

I want to exclude the values of column 2 based on the big value of column3 and also sign changing in that column. I mean from num 0 to num 3 of column 2 becomes list A and from num 4 to num 6 becomes list B.
I have written a thing but it is not usable.

```
# To find the bigest value in col 3
def find_threshold(arr, value):
    for i, a in enumerate(arr):
        if a == value:
            break
    return i
# To append the new lists based on sign
def list_creator:
   list=[]

   for i in range(1,len(arr)-1):
      if np.sign(i)!=np.sign(arr[i])
          list.append(arr[i])
   return list
```

Comment: I think `listA` should be from `0 to 2` and `listB` should be from `3 to 6`. you want to have as much lists as there are sign changing ? what do you mean by exclude col2 on basis of big value for `col3`

Comment: @ZainArshad I meant defining a function to look at column 3 first and finding the biggest value of that column then based on the sign of values of the column3 separating values of column 2. if you see, in column 3 before and after the biggest value we have sign-changing so I'd like to exclude values of column 2 based on that.